# Can't redefine font-size of BootStrap's dropdown-menu class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having the hardest time trying to redefine the font-size of BootStrap's .dropdown-menu class.

The Firefox inspector says it's from .dropdown-menu (inherited from ul), so I tried ul.dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu but with no luck.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"></div>
        <div id="myMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>First list item</li>
                <li id="my-messages" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Messages</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu">
                        <li>Dropdown list item</li>
                        ...
```

Any advise? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work fine, try to put !important maybe it fixes it

Comment: Thanks, but !important didn't work

Comment: You want the text of the dropdown itself to be larger, right? Not the `li` options under it?

Comment: Can you post all of your relevant code? I'm having no issues here either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're using it in conjunction with a nav?

I was able to do this with the nav and a bit of CSS.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/vipqI37jUL)**

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav > li {
  font-size: 20px;
  }
.dropdown-menu {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your bootstrap above and then your regular css file in header. And then write your css in style.css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Alright, you've provided the correct way to apply the styling, but what about the styling he's actually asking for?

Comment: He can get this by firefox inspector as he informed this in question.

Comment: He's not asking how to properly add the CSS, as in what order it needs to be added in, he's asking what CSS needs to be written to actually achieve what he's asking for. You're not answering the question at all.